# Can I change my current OS X partition from case-insentitive to case-sensitive?

Tags: partitioning

I have a [Mac OS X v10.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion) system, and I ran into some issues because my file-system is case-insensitive.

When you create a new partition in the `Disk Utility`, it lets me choose to use either of those:

1. Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)
2. Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

Is it possible to change an existing partition from `(Journaled)` to `(Case-sensitive, Journaled)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'll need to reformat the partition to change its case sensitivity.

Edit: Actually, I just found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15080/convert-a-partition-from-case-sensitive-to-case-insensitive), which is a very similar problem. It looks like something called [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) worked to change a partition from case-sensitive to case-insensitive, and I would assume it could do it the other way around as well, as what you need to do is actually simpler.